# Load custom Data into a tensorflow pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network, data-pipeline, tf.data.dataset

I am trying to implement this code which loads the data from the
official tensorflow dataset to get it to load my data placed on my google drive

```
dataset, metadata = tfds.load('cycle_gan/horse2zebra',
                              with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
train_horses, train_zebras = dataset['trainA'], dataset['trainB']
```

How can I get it to load my images into classes from classes A and B to my train_horses and train_zebras class

```
train_dataset=tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    '/content/drive/MyDrive/ColorGan', labels='inferred', label_mode='int',
    class_names=None, color_mode='rgb', batch_size=32, image_size=(256,
    256), shuffle=True, seed=2000, validation_split=0.2, subset='training',
    interpolation='bilinear', follow_links=False,
    crop_to_aspect_ratio=False)
test_dataset=tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    '/content/drive/MyDrive/ColorGan', labels='inferred', label_mode='int',
    class_names=None, color_mode='rgb', batch_size=32, image_size=(256,
    256), shuffle=True, seed=2000, validation_split=0.2, subset='validation',
    interpolation='bilinear', follow_links=False,
    crop_to_aspect_ratio=False)

train_horses, train_zebras = train_dataset['A'],train_dataset['B']
```

It gives me error that it is not scriptable what can I so that the data loads in the format shown in the top code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use **tf.data** for pre-processing your dataset as it is proven to be  more efficient than **ImageDataGenerator**
as well as **image_dataset_from_directory**. [this](https://quantumai.in/tf-data/) blog describes the directory structure that you should use and also it has the code to implement from tf.data for custom dataset from scratch.

Comment: The link is dead. Please add a code example to complete the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Sample working code to create the Tensorflow datapipeline**

```
import pathlib
data_dir = pathlib.Path('/content/images/horses')
import tensorflow as tf
batch_size = 16
img_height = 180
img_width = 180
train_horses = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

import pathlib
data_dir = pathlib.Path('/content/images/zebras')

import tensorflow as tf
batch_size = 16
img_height = 180
img_width = 180
train_zebras = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

ds = train_horses.concatenate(train_zebras)
```